# android- adding viewgroup to window using WindowManager

Tags: android

I am a noob developer, I am currently working on a floating app project, my problem is "How do I add a Layout to window using WindowManager?" I have a floating view added to the window using a WindowManager, but now I want to add a LinearLayout the window so what should I do now?? There's no methods like windowManager.addViewGroup(); afaik (Sorry for my english tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewGroup` is a sub class of `View` (and thus `LinearLayout`)... so you can call

```
WindowManager.addView(LinearLayout)
```

Comment: Yep, why not, but sorry, don't have enough reputation to vote up lol